# Tags for lines and planes?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Quite recently (it can still be seen in the [list of new tags](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=new)) the tag [line](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/line) was created. (As far as I can say, it was created in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1147661/revisions). Or at least it was the first post using this tag that I saw. It was later removed from that post, but added to other posts before it was removed from the system, see also [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3740/conversation/creation-of-line-tag).)

There are several natural questions:

- Should we keep the tag? Will it be useful?
- What should be content of the tag? (The [tag-info](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/line) is empty at the moment.)
- Most tags are in plural. Should [lines](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lines) be added instead or at least as a synonym?
- Should we add similar tag for [planes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planes)?

We have many tags about specific geometric objects: [circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/circle), [triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/triangle), [quadrilateral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quadrilateral), [conic-sections](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conic-sections), [spheres](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spheres), [polyhedra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polyhedra), ... Lines and planes are definitely important in geometry, too. I can imagine this tag being useful, for example, for many questions in [analytic-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analytic-geometry). Many questions about them can appear also in [linear-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-algebra) and [affine-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/affine-geometry). But it would definitely be useful to clarify the usage of the tag at least a bit. (At least if we want to keep this tag.)

I am not very active in [geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry)-related topics. So I suppose that opinion of users who are interested in geometry questions and follow such questions on this site would be a great input into the discussion about these tags.

Comment: "It's a line! It's a plane! It's Geometry Man!"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I really don't think that such tags are focused enough to be of any real use to the site. They are highly unlikely to be uniformly applied, and so their value as search aids would be negligible, at best.

Comment: Since your answer has 5 upvotes (more than we usually get on tag-related issues), I have accepted it and started retagging the questions. [Here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20224505#20224505) is list of the question which were tagged with this tag. (Just in case we decide to reverse this decision later.)